# Periodic Binary Strings

Tags: algorithm

Is there any efficient algorithms to check whether a binary string is periodic or not?

Let S be a binary string and H be the set of sub strings  of S. Then S is said to be periodic if it can be obtained by concatenating one or more times, at least one h in H, also h != S .

Comment: H can be the set of all *prefixes* `p` of S, with `len(S) mod len(p) == 0`.

Comment: @chill Yes, doing like that we can reduce the size of H.

Comment: we dont have to check for all the prefixes , but all prefixes p , with len(p)*2 = len(S)

Comment: No, the period may be shorter, example "abababababab".

Comment: In the above example when prefix length is 2 then we can determine the  string as periodic. We don't have to go beyond 6.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220313/preperiodic-periodic-or-aperiodic-binary-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initial string S with length Len.  Double the string (really we need S + half of S). Search for occurrence of initial string S in doubled string SS, beginning from 2nd position, ending at Len/2 + 1. If such occurence exists with position P, then S is periodic with period P - 1.

S = abbaabbaabba Len = 12
SS = abbaabbaabbaabbaabbaabba

Searching from 2nd to 7th position, S found at P=5, period = 4

S = abaabaabaabb
SS = abaabaabaabbabaabaabaabb

S doesn't occur in SS (except for 1 and L+1), no period exists

**P.S.** Note due to useful Venkatesh comment:
We need to add minimal possible periodic unit, it's length is L/2 for even-size strings, and maximum divisor of L for odd-size strings (if length is prime number, string cannot be periodic). Simple factorization methods have O(N^1/2)  complexity, more complex - O(N^1/4), so sometimes it is worth to factorize length to avoid unnecessary comparison of  long strings.

Comment: @Pentium10 Are you really observing 1110111011 substring at 4th position in <> part of <1110111011111011>1011 superstring?

Comment: No, but in this case the string to find is: 1110, that's what repeats itself.

Comment: This problem assumes full (true? don't know exact term from stringology) periodicity S=(X)^n, rather than S=(X)^nY, because string should be obtained by concatenation pattern some times

Comment: @MBo if length of S is odd, Should I check from 2 to ceil(length / 2 + 1) or floor(length / 2 + 1) ?

Comment: Floor is enough. See addition in post.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it is possible to improve on this, but I would have started by breaking the length of S (I'll call that L) to prime factors, and checking for a period of length of S/f for each prime factor f (len(h) must divide len(S) and I'm since not looking for the shortest possible h, prime L/len(h) is enough).

As to improvements, random check order would help in some circumstances (to prevent constructing input for worse case scenarios, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First of all for this to happen it's necessary that length(h) divides length(S).

If `k = length(S)/length(h)`, then for a given `k` it's easy to check whether the string is periodic.

Indeed, it's periodic if the number represented by S is divisible by 100..0100..0...100..0.
That's the number which is of length length(S), has k blocks of equal length and each block has only the highest bit set.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static boolean isPeriodic(String string) {
int stringLength = string.length();
if (stringLength <= 1) {
    return false;
}
boolean flag = true;

for (int i = 1; i <= stringLength / 2; i++) {
if (string.length() % i == 0) {
if (flag && i > 1) {
    return flag;
}
flag = true;
for (int j = i; j < stringLength;) {

if ((j + i) <= stringLength) {

if (string.substring(0, i).equals(
        string.substring(j, j + i))) {
    j = j + i;
    continue;
} else {
    flag = false;
    break;

}
} else {
    break;
}

}
}

}
return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a `O(m + (n-1))` algorithm (where m is the input length, and n is the cycle length).

Based of the [Knuth Morris Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm, it iterates over the input string, checking to see if the substring `input[0:i]` is a repeated pattern. If it finds a character in the input string that isn't in the pattern, then `i` is updated to become the index of that character. This means characters in the string are not compared more than once.

```
public static String findSequence(String input) {
  out: for (int i = 0; i < input.length();) {
    for (int j = i; j < input.length(); j++) {
      if(input.charAt(j % (i+1)) != input.charAt(j)) {
        i = j;
        continue out;
      }
    }
    return (String) input.subSequence(0, i + 1);
  }
  return ""; // Impossible
}
```